# Meaningless bits in CIDR notation

Tags: ipv4, subnet, network

Is specifying meaningless bits valid syntax in CIDR notation? For instance, the netmask of `192.168.13.0/16` is `255.255.0.0`. In this case, the last two octets (`00001101 00000000`) are meaningless because any value between `192.168.0.0` and `192.168.255.255` (inclusive) is in range. I'm curious what's considered **valid** in CIDR notation.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  They're not "meaningless bits", they're "host bits" !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a valid syntax.  Every host on a network has an IP address, and it's also important to know what subnet it's a part of.  You need that information to configure the host.  So 192.168.13.0/16 tells you what the host IP is and also what the subnet is.

If we follow your idea to the logical extreme, everything is in the range of 0.0.0.0/0, so we don't need to specify IP addressing at all.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify an address longer than the bits in the mask, you are generally referring to a host address. In your example, `192.168.13.0/16` would be a host on the `192.168.0.0/16` network. That gives you the host address and mask (similar to `192.168.13.0 255.255.0.0`, except in shortened form), from which you can derive all type of network information. See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious what's considered valid in CIDR notation

It depends on the context.

Afaict "CIDR notation" is not formally defined anywhere. In practice though CIDR notation is used in two different ways.

- To identify a block of addresses, for example the target of a route or the filter for a firewall rule. In this case the convention is that the "host" bits are all zeros. The software I have tried enforces this convention, but I can't be sure all software does.
- To specify an assignment of IP address and subnet mask to an interface. In this case the host bits are meaningful.

Comment: You should check out [RFC 4632](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4632#section-3.1). ;-)